# VirtualBox not working

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, virtualbox

When ever i try to start a virtual machine i get this error.

[image: Virtualbox error image]

I have Ubuntu 12.04 (64bit) and `Kernel Linux 3.2.0-27-generic`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the `owner not root` in the error.

Did you install the Adobe Flash plugin? If so check the directory ownership of `/usr/`. This needs to be owned by `root` and is more than likely changed by Adobe Flash plugin.

```
cd /
sudo chown root:root usr
```

And try again. There could be more directories involved.

---

More information:

- [Virtualbox website](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=39179#p189623) (is also about Mac systems)
- [Virtualbox website](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/7889)
- [Ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1857854) (states /usr and /usr/lib)